When replacing thermal paste, do existing thermal pads have to be replaced?
I'm just replacing thermal paste on a laptop.
I've found however there are some thermal pads applied with about 3 years, already with the shape of the heatsink.
Do I have to replace the termal pads as well? I've read that they last about 6 years, but I'm concerned that if the heatsink isn't well tightened, the existing thermal pads will not make contact


In general, it's always best to replace thermal pads whenever you're in the system. However, if you inspect them and they aren't dried out or falling apart (they should have some squish to them and leave some oil residue on your finger) then you can get away with just doing the paste.
Depending on what exactly this looks like, you might even be better off replacing the pads with paste. Paste will almost always offer a better thermal transference.
